# How can I handle invisible new line characters in Java?

Tags: java, newline, invisible, character-arrays

I am currently working on the code for a game in Java. I am supposed to fill an array with characters from a .txt file. The problem is that my programm also stores the invisible new line characters from the file and as a result the array is not filled correctly. I have already tried to replace the invisible characters but the result was disastrous (my array would only be filled for the first line and the rest would remain empty) here is my block of code used for the array:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        char background[][] = new char [14][20];

    try {

        FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("background.txt");
            int r;
            for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<20;j++){//<<THIS LINE WAS CHANGED
                    while((r = fileinput.read()) != -1){
                        char c = (char) r;
                        background[i][j] = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            fileinput.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0;i<14;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
                System.out.print(background[i][j]);
            }
        }
}




}
```

Also the format of the .txt file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/NynJGkFk. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Read the line as a String, call the [.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method on the line, and then use .toCharArray() to split it into chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows use "\r\n" to check new line or fetch the platform-specific one from system properties

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```